# Trying to use Bootstrap Accordion with only one panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am using the Bootstrap accordion on 2 pages on a site. However on one of them there is only one panel that is needed. I only want to show the contents of the panel if a user wants to see it. (It's a transcript of a related video.)

The problem I am having is that the accordion opens nicely, but it will not close. is this because there is no other panel to open ad trigger the first one to close?

I would be happy using another method that allows about 3 lines of the transcript to show with a button to open the rest and close it as well.

The accordion is here: http://awbassociation.org/awba-video/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there's something messing it up on your page... when [**you pull it out and run it by iself**](http://www.bootply.com/sAIxgPtBhX), it runs fine. You've got a lot of extra `<p>` tags in there, but that's not really relevant

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some js conflicted because it will collapse whatever one panel or multi panel. I have just tried and its work.

Please you can show you tried code too. It will easier to find solution

Here is the screenshot http://prntscr.com/6cmb68